# Xcode TableView - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I'm trying to learn table views and I've hit a snag. I have the view delegate and datasource connected correctly in Storyboard, but I get the following runtime error when I get to the section of my app containing the table view.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationItem tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here's the chunk from my implementation file

```
@implementation CraftingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Detail";

    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is displaying because `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is being sent to an object of type `UINavigationItem` while it seems like your `CraftingViewController` class is probably of type `UITableViewController`. I would make sure that you have connected your delegate to the correct class, because it doesn't seem like `CraftingViewController` is connected properly.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I had the table view connected to the navigation controller rather than the viewcontroller

Answer (score -1):

if the datasource is controller of the nib file.

please check alloc of this controller use "CraftingViewController" not "UIViewController"